# Converting ValidatorJS isISIN to Typescript and getting error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parseint

I'm getting the following error when converting `isISIN` from validatorjs to typescript:

```
(parameter) character: string
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
lib.es5.d.ts(454, 53): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
lib.es5.d.ts(454, 5): The last overload is declared here.
```

This is the code:

```
  const checksumStr = target.replace(/[A-Z]/g, character => (parseInt(character, 36)));
```

VSCOde draws a redline under `(parseInt(character, 36)))` with the error.

Thoughts?  Should the `parseInt` not be there?

This is the entire method just for reference:

```
/**
 * Test whether the target string is an ISBN number.
 * 
 * @param target The string
 * @return true if the `target` string is an ISIN number, false otherwise
 */
export function isISIN(target:string) {
  assertString(target);
  if (!isin.test(target)) {
    return false;
  }

  const checksumStr = target.replace(/[A-Z]/g, character => (parseInt(character, 36)));

  let sum = 0;
  let digit;
  let tmpNum;
  let shouldDouble = true;
  for (let i = checksumStr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    digit = checksumStr.substring(i, (i + 1));
    tmpNum = parseInt(digit, 10);
    if (shouldDouble) {
      tmpNum *= 2;
      if (tmpNum >= 10) {
        sum += tmpNum + 1;
      } else {
        sum += tmpNum;
      }
    } else {
      sum += tmpNum;
    }
    shouldDouble = !shouldDouble;
  }

  return parseInt(target.substr(target.length - 1), 10) === (10000 - sum) % 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) returns a `number` and [string.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) expects to receive a `string` as replacement.

Anyway, the code works, that should be a warning.

To fix it, transform the parseInt result to string. Something like:

```js
  const replacer = character => {
    const intValue = parseInt(character, 36);
    return intValue? intValue.toString() : ''
  }

  const checksumStr = target.replace(/[A-Z]/g, replacer);
```